# Даны 4 числа типа int. Сравнить их и вывести наименьшее на консоль

Tags: java

Я сделал так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = in.nextInt();
    int b = in.nextInt();
    int c = in.nextInt();
    int d = in.nextInt();
    int x =0;
    if (a<b){
        if (a<c){
            if (a<d)x =a;
        }
        else if (b<a){
            if (b<c)
                if (b<d)x =b;
            }
            else if (c<a){
                if (c<b)
                    if (c<d)x =c;
                }
                else if (d<b){
                    if (d<c)
                        if (d<a)x =d;
                    }
                    System.out.println(x);
    }
            }
            }
```

при вводе чисел 5,7,3,9 выдаёт 5, а должен 3.
Подскажите в чём ошибка.`5 7 3 9
5`

Comment: а где вы хоть раз c или d присваиваете?.. Короче if - else раза в 4 больше должно быть

Comment: В массив их поместить и отсортировать - самое элегантное решение на мой взгляд

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Я вот смотрю на ответы и поражаюсь.
**Вот самый простой вариант решения:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = in.nextInt();
    int b = in.nextInt();
    int c = in.nextInt();
    int d = in.nextInt();

    int answer = Math.min( Math.min(a,b), Math.min(c,d) );
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int count = scanner.nextInt();
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        numbers.add(scanner.nextInt());

    Collections.sort(numbers);

    if (count != 0)
        System.out.println(numbers.get(0));
}
```

Первый раз, нужно ввести количество символов, затем вводятся сами числа. В результате в консоль выводится минимальное из них.

Answer (score 0):

Легче и правильнее сделать такое с использованием коллекций. Например - ArrayList.

```
int tmp;
ArrayList<Integer> inputList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int I = 0; I < 4; I++){
    inputList.add(in.nextInt());
}
//сортировка пузырек
//можно еще вместо ручной использовать метод класса Collections - sort
//Collections.sort(inputList);
for(int I = 0; I < inputList.size()-1; I++){
  for(int J = 0; J < inputList.size()-I-1; J++){
    if(inputList.get(j) > inputList.get(j+1)){
      tmp = inputList.get(j);
      inputList.add(j,inputList.get(j+1));
      inputList.add(j+1,tmp);
     }
   }
}

for(Integer item : inputList){
System.out.print(' ' + item);
}
```

Если Вас преподаватель заставляет вот так вот вручную сравнивать 4 и больше числа, значит скорее всего что-то с ним чертовски неправильно...

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = in.nextInt();
    int b = in.nextInt();
    int c = in.nextInt();
    int d = in.nextInt();
    int x =0;
    if (a<b &a<c&a<d)x =a;

        else if (b<a&b<c&b<d)x =b;
            else if (c<a&c<b&c<d)x =c;
                else if (d<b&d<c&d<a)x =d;

                    System.out.println(x);
    }
            }
```

Comment: только вместо `&` можно (или часто даже нужно) использовать `&&` - при этом если какое-либо из условий не выполнится, то остальные уже проверяться не будут

Answer (score -3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int result = 0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Введите a: ");
    a = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Введите b: ");
    b = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Введите c: ");
    c = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Введите d: ");
    d = in.nextInt();

    if ((a < b) && (a < c) && (a < d)) {
        System.out.println("А - наименьшее");
    } else if ((b < a) && (b < c) && (b < d)) {
        System.out.println("B - наименьшее");
    } else if ((c < a) && (c < b) && (c < d)) {
        System.out.println("С - наименьшее");
    } else if ((d < a) && (d < b) && (d < c)) {
        System.out.println("D  наименьшее");
    }

}
```

Comment: Охохо. Коллеги, не стоит ссориться. )

Comment: @Михаил добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow. В первый раз вы использовали инструмент для оформления кода на Js+html+css — с другими языками он не работает. Но с этим вроде разобрались уже. Что Eugene намекал на нерабочий код — скорее всего речь шла о пропущенной скобке `}`.

Comment: По сути вопроса: как вы думаете, что будет, если среди введённых чисел будет хотя бы два одинаковых наименьших? Что вернёт программа? (минусы наверняка по этой причине)

Comment: А ещё вы выводите номер наименьшего числа, а в задаче — значение. )